# FoamTree: visualization already embedded in the element

Tags: javascript, visualization

**Error: While bindig foam tree**

```
FoamTree: visualization already embedded in the element
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue comes when you try to re-render the foam tree. To solve this issue remove the data-foamtree attribute with following way :-

```
var portfolioExcessReturn = document.getElementById(
            'foamTreeIdName'
          ) as any;
        if (portfolioExcessReturn) {
          portfolioExcessReturn.removeAttribute('data-foamtree');
        }
```